# Why are items outside the view?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

I had two buttons in a UIView, then I add the view to main view, but I eventually got something like this:

[image]

As you can see these two buttons went outside the red view.

I wanted a little bit of margin on top, so I use `constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[buttonGroup]-10-|"`, I'm not sure if that matters.

Here's the original code:

```
- (UIButton*) getButtonWithTitle: (NSString*) title
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

    button.layer.borderColor  = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    button.layer.borderWidth  = 0.5f;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    return button;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    UIButton *loginBtn    = [self getButtonWithTitle:@"Login"];
    UIButton *registerBtn = [self getButtonWithTitle:@"Register"];

    UIView *buttonGroup = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [buttonGroup setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [buttonGroup addSubview: loginBtn];
    [buttonGroup addSubview: registerBtn];
    [self.view addSubview: buttonGroup];
    [buttonGroup setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loginBtn, registerBtn, buttonGroup);
    [buttonGroup addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[loginBtn]-20-[registerBtn(==loginBtn)]-|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary
      ]];

    NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[buttonGroup]-10-|"
                                    options:0
                                    metrics:nil
                                    views:viewsDictionary];
    NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[buttonGroup]-|"
                                    options:0
                                    metrics:nil
                                    views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints: horizontalConstraints];
    [self.view addConstraints: verticalConstraints];
}
```

**EDIT**

The constraints I added:

```
[buttonGroup addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[loginBtn]-|"
                                         options:0
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:viewsDictionary
  ]];
[buttonGroup addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[registerBtn]-|"
                                         options:0
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:viewsDictionary
  ]];
```

It looks like I did extra work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never created any vertical constraints between the buttons and buttonGroup; add those, and you should be good. Also, you shouldn't set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO for the controller's self.view (only for subviews that you add to it).

Comment: I added two vertical constraints on both buttons and it worked. But is that the correct way? I  used to think it could be done with only one vertical constraint

Comment: @warl0ck, what 2 constraints did you add? You should only need one.

Comment: I have updated the question with the two lines I added

Comment: @warl0ck,  Those two constraints are fine. You could just have one, and in the options, use align all tops and align all bottoms (and maybe give whichever button you add the constraint on, a height).

Answer (score 1):

In the VFL , the | means the superview, but your two buttons(loginBtn, registerBtn) are the subviews of the buttonGroup. So you should define the V relation about the loginBtn, registerBtn with the buttonGroup. As rdelmar said, the self.view should set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to No. This can close the autosizingmask function. I think the best way to do this things in xib or storyboard.